# Implement Login system in python using flask_login with different user types

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am trying to create a college system using flask but I have a problem with log in system basically I have two classes Teacher class and Student class the problem is that I cant figure a way to make the login manager handle the two classes login at the same time only one can log in and when the other class try to log in it log me as the class what I mean is when I setup the login manager to accept student it works with the student but when I try to login as a teacher it searches in the student table instead of teacher table I don't know if I explained it right but i hope code snippet help

this is models

```
attend = db.Table('attend',
    db.Column('teacher_id',db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('teacher.id')),
    db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('student.id'))
)

class Teacher(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)
    email=db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False,unique=True)
    password=db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)
    department=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)
    students=db.relationship('Student',secondary=attend,backref='students',lazy='dynamic')


    def type_auth(self):
        return True

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'name:{self.name} email:{self.email} department:{self.department}'


class Student(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    year=db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    grades = db.relationship('Grades', backref='Rates', lazy='dynamic')

    def type_auth(self):
        return False
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'name:{self.name} email:{self.email} year:{self.year}'
```

this login manager

```
def create_app():
    app=Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    app.config['SECERT_KEY'] = '1853d2c8983cff3b'
    app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWITCH']='Cyborg'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .auth import auth
    from .routes import routes

    app.register_blueprint(auth,prefix_url='/')
    app.register_blueprint(routes,prefix_url='/')

    login_manger=LoginManager()
    login_manger.login_view='auth.login'
    login_manger.login_message_category='info'
    login_manger.init_app(app)

    @login_manger.user_loader
    def user_loader(id):
        #i need help here

    return app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user_loader` callback received an `id` as an argument and from that information is expected to return an instance of whatever you have defined as your "User" class.  You have effectively defined *two* "User" classes, and in the current configuration there is no way for the user loader, if passed "1", to determine whether it should return the `Teacher` with id 1 or the `Student` with id 1.

A better design might be to move `email` and `password` into a new `User` class, and create one-to-one relationships between `User` and `Student` and `Teacher`.  You can add some validation to ensure that a `User` cannot relate to both a `Student` and a `Teacher`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. When a user logs in, search in both the teacher and student database and then log them in. While logging, create a session variable say session['teacher'] = true, to identify the role when the person has logged in.

Or

2. You may also try giving an identifier for the user to choose. For example: I am a: Teacher(chekcbox)  Student(checkbox). Depending on the check selected, look into that db.